# What is a basic explanation of Finite Fields?

Tags: finite-field

I have zero background and I have never seen these symbols before. Can someone explain what is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple explanation: A finite field, is a finite set, meaning multiplication, addition, subtraction and division are defined and follow the rules of field axioms. It contains a finite number of elements. A basic example of Finite Fields are

```
p = prime
modulo P
```

If you are looking for more information, regarding programming with Finite Fields

See this source: https://jeremykun.com/2014/03/13/programming-with-finite-fields/

It might seem a bit wild, but if you read more about it, it will start to make sense.
I'd also research into Finite Field Arithmetic.

I hope my answer was useful
- yosh